# jQuery - Sliding vertically aligned column

Tags: jquery

I have two columns, they are both floated to the left.

Inside the left column I have a 'trigger' to hide the right column, this makes the left column expand 100% when the right column is hidden. Right now I am able to make the right column appear back, but the problem is that the right column wraps under the left column (of course, the left column has 100% width) and not to next to it like it initially started.

I'm not a jQuery/JavaScript programmer, but I would think I'm in a good direction with my jQuery code.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="left-col">
  <div id="trigger"><a href="#">Toggle</a></div>
    <p>...</p>
  </div>
  <div id="right-col">Right Column</div>
  <br class="clear">
</div>
```

This is the jQuery I have so far:

```
$(function() { 
  $("#left-col").addClass("wide80");
  $("#trigger a").click(function(){  
    $("#right-col").animate({width:'toggle'},350);
    $("#left-col").animate({width:'100%'},350); return false
   });
});
```

Any help you can give me would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this -- something along these lines should work

```
$(function() { 
    $("#left-col").addClass("wide80");
    $("#trigger a").click(function(){
        var leftCol = $("#left-col");

        if( leftCol.data('expanded') ) {
            leftCol.animate({width:'50%'},350);
            leftCol.data( 'expanded', false );
        } else {
            leftCol.animate({width:'100%'},350);
            leftCol.data( 'expanded', true );
        }

        $("#right-col").animate({width:'toggle'},350);

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Interesting. I was about to suggest putting the second animation into the first one's callback function, but this seems much better.

Comment: Perfect! :D

I did small modifications to it since the right column was appearing for half a second wrapped under the left column right after clicking the Toggle button. I also did some changes to the CSS classes for semantics reasons, that's why some names are a little different. 

I have a very hard time understanding the if/else, var, I had no idea about '.data'... oh well.

See the final working code in the post below.

Thanks a lot Kerry!

Comment: Not a problem! Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Final working code, thanks to Kerry:

```
$(function() { 
  $("#left-col").addClass("wide");
  $("#trigger a").click(function(){
    var leftCol = $("#left-col");

    if( leftCol.data('expanded') ) {
        leftCol.animate({width:'60%'},350);
        leftCol.data( 'expanded', false );
        $("#right-col").toggle(350);
    } else {
        leftCol.animate({width:'100%'},350);
        leftCol.data( 'expanded', true );
        $("#right-col").hide();
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```